# SpringFramework @Scheduled is executing the method twice but console log prints record of only one execution

Tags: java, spring-boot

The scheduled task[payment transfer] is executing twice but console logs has track of only one execution.

The only proof for the duplicate run is that the transfer history in database has two entry with the same schedule id with difference of 1second in executed time.

Main class

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {
        "com.`*`",
        "com.`*`"
},
        exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})<br>
public class PaymentsSchedulerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PaymentsSchedulerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my component class where the method is annotated with `@Scheduled`. It is intended to run at 00:30 Hrs Local time every day.

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ScheduledTask {

    private final ISchedulerService iSchedulerService;
```

this is the method that is running as a ghost as we couldn't find any information in logs on the duplicated execution.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${scheduler.jobs.repeating-transfer.cron}")
public void scheduleTask() {          
  // cron: '0 30 0 * * *
  log.info("Execute")<br>
}
```

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but: how many instances of your app/service do you have running?

Comment: Just one. The blocker here is why the duplicate run is not leaving any trace in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

A blunder by devops team, they had run the scheduler service in DR environment connected to prod db. Hence both Prod and DR service were running the batch which lead to duplication.